# Office 365: Single task to be done by multiple users

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, tasks

With Microsoft Planner, we can add multiple people to a single task, but if anyone of them marks it as complete the whole task will be marked as complete.

But I would like to assign a task to my team which each of them needs to complete individually and I would like to keep a track of who has completed and who has not. Is this possible by using an office add-in?

Answer (score 0):

You would need duplicate planner tasks for each user.  You could, however, move out to SharePoint Online and use a SharePoint Task list and attach an approval workflow/flow that required all individuals to approve.

Comment: Can you please point me to a webpage that demonstrates that process of creating a workflow you're talking about? I'm not sure how to create a Sharepoint Task list.